# SQL Server 2000 - Is there a fast way of deleting backup history?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

We have a SQL Server 2000 instance where the `MSDB` has grown to a huge size due to the backup history never having been deleted in several years. I would like to purge the backup history completely (I don't see why it's needed) and free up the disk space used by all this data.

I realise you can use the `sp_delete_backuphistory` command, but this is far too slow (nothing happens in 2+ hours) and while it's executing the transaction log file grows to fill the entire disk (several GB). SQL Server 2000 does not appear to support doing this database by database.

I need to find a way of deleting all the data which doesn't fill the disk up first. So either deleting in stages so the log doesn't grow to big, or perhaps using truncate table somehow, but I'm not sure if there's a safe way to do this, and as I'm not a SQL expert, I wouldn't really know how to do this without destroying my `MSDB` database!

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reduce the number of rows you delete in one go.  The first parameter to [sp_delete_backuphistory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188328.aspx) is the oldest day to keep.

```
EXEC sp_delete_backuphistory '2000-01-01'
EXEC sp_delete_backuphistory '2001-01-01'
EXEC sp_delete_backuphistory '2002-01-01'
...
```

It can also help to lower the recovery model to `Simple` if it's currently at `Full`.

Answer (score 2):

I use something like the following:

```
declare @oldest_date datetime, @newest_date datetime

select @oldest_date = min(backup_start_date) from backupset
select @newest_date = dateadd(day, -45, getdate())

while(@oldest_date <= @newest_date)
begin
   exec sp_delete_backuphistory @oldest_date
   set @oldest_date = dateadd(day, 7, @oldest_date)
end
```

This will delete a week's worth of history at a time until you're caught up.  The nice thing is that you can stick this in a job and run it periodically (weekly, for instance) and it'll do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

First take a backup,
Then create database for each year and restore database from backup file for one year data.
then clear all log file after take all process.